# List files with memory space older than 14 days

Tags: shell-script

In shell scripting how to find 14 days older than files and directory in a account

I need to list them with their memory space

ex:

```
0 ./.vxz.tmp
658 ./.zshrc
6 ./dummy.txt
2.1K ./ss1s:
489K ./sss.txt
154K ./ced.txt
406 ./test.csv
```

Comment: Please don't use _Urgent Help!!!_ etc in the title - it doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find files in the current directory that are more than 14 days old and list their sizes (in kilobytes) and their names, use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +14  -printf '%k %p\n'
```

#### How it works

- `find .`

  Start looking for files in the current directory.
- `-maxdepth 1`

  Look only in the current directory rather than recursively looking into subdirectories.
- `-mtime +14`

  Look for files that are more than 14 days old.

  Note that, because of the way that `find` rounds off days to an integer, "more than 14 days" means at least 15 days.  See `man find` for details on how `find` does the round-off.
- `-printf '%k %p\n'`

  For each file found, print the size in kB and the name.

#### Variation

If you want to look only for regular files (no directory, block devices, etc.), then add `-type f` as follows:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14  -printf '%k %p\n'
```